# TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetParent' of null when navigatin to another page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using a code to stick a div on top when scrolling and the div reaches the top.

The code is working correctly but i'm getting a error when navigating to another page .

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetParent' of null
```

My code

```
render() {
  var startProductBarPos = -1;
  window.onscroll = function () {
    var bar = document.getElementById('nav');

    if (startProductBarPos < 0) startProductBarPos = findPosY(bar);

    if (window.pageYOffset > startProductBarPos) {
      bar.style.position = 'fixed';
      bar.style.width = '58.6%'
      bar.style.top = 0;
    } else {
      bar.style.position = 'relative';
      bar.style.width = '100%'
    }

  };

  function findPosY(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (typeof (obj.offsetParent) != 'undefined' && obj.offsetParent) {
      while (obj.offsetParent) {
        curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        obj = obj.offsetParent;
      }

      curtop += obj.offsetTop;
    } else if (obj.y) 
        curtop += obj.y;

    return curtop;
  };

  return(
    <div className="trait_type_header" id="nav">
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is line it's showing where the error is.

```
if (typeof (obj.offsetParent) != 'undefined' && obj.offsetParent) {
```

I think when navigating to another page `obj` becomes null. If that's the case how can i fix it?

Comment: If you track back through the code, that means your line `var bar = document.getElementById('nav');` is failing to find the element.

Comment: put your js after the html part

Comment: this is reactjs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to change

```
if (typeof (obj.offsetParent) != 'undefined' && obj.offsetParent)
```

to

```
if (obj && obj.offsetParent)
```

Comment: where should i use this?

Comment: but after you will change that - you'll get an error in this line else if (obj.y), so change it also to if (obj && obj.y)